# Why is the placeholder text in KSTokenView not aligned?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, kstokenview

I'm using KSTokenView to make a dropdown menu, but somehow the placeholder text before you search is not aligned. Why is this? (KSTokenView is a subclass of UIView if that helps)

[image: the search placeholder text should be aligned with Component]

EDIT: The only thing I did differently than the example is the sizing of my box. So when I set it to 30 height and 300 width it is aligned perfectly. I guess that's just the way it has to be.

Comment: I just downloaded the Example app from KSTokenView repository and doesn't encounter the bug. Can you provide more infos on how you setup  the component in your project (iOS version, Xcode version, device used) ?

Comment: Hey, I edited the question but I think I basically "solved" it. The only thing different from the example and mine is that the uiview's dimension are different. So when I set it to the one in the example it is aligned.

Comment: This issue fixed in latest code as of today.

Answer (score 0):

KSTokenView doesn't seem to provide a public alignement property.

There's a `paddingX` property accessible for the title though so you could try it to have a satisfying result but it doesn't look like a good solution.

Also the way KSTokenView works I don't see why you'd want to have the title centered (where would the token go then?).

GIF for illustration :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying? I'm just asking about aligning the placeholder text along with the promptext I don't care if the title is centered.

Comment: Whoops think you talked about horizontal alignment. Let me take a look.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if SO notifies you when I update, but the problem was that my box's dimension wasn't similar to how he has it in his example. Thank you for trying to help though